# How to insert text into popup window using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate a web page using selenium WebDriver. I can move towards the webpages and can able to do all tasks on parent pages. But at one place I am getting a POPUP window which asks username and password. I am unable to identify the username and password text box id's, how can I find the element (TextBox) and send the username and password through selenium webDriver code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this by using your web URL,

```
@Test
public void testlinkedin() throws Exception {
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/");  //Use your web URL
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Up")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.fb-btn")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

Set <String>handles = driver.getWindowHandles();//To handle multiple windows
firstWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
handles.remove(firstWinHandle);
String winHandle=handles.iterator().next();
if (winHandle!=firstWinHandle){
     secondWinHandle=winHandle;

driver.switchTo().window(secondWinHandle);   //Switch to popup window
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Password");
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("__CONFIRM__")).click();}
```

Make sure to declare these string variables as,

```
public String firstWinHandle;  
public String secondWinHandle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the new pop-up window to select its elements. Here is an example to switch to the new window:

`String handle = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];`   // 1 stands for the new window and 0 for the parent window

```
driver.switchTo(handle);
```

Now you can select your elements present in this window.

**Note: ** To get back to original window you again need to switch back to it with `0` as the index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the popup window is HTTP basic authenticated site. If so, then you cannot use the window handles as stated in previous answer, but in that case you have to send the username and password directly to URL request:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@your-test-site.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me as I used like this...

```
    String handle = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString();
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
```